# Android see old push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification

Can I find old received push notifications somewhere in the phone, log file, etc.?

Can't find any information with Google. Thanks.

Edit: Talking about already received notifications, before writing this post. Don't have a custom logging system in the app. Need to find them somewhere in the device. Maybe some hidden log file or buried somewhere? I have a rooted device.

Comment: Why dont you save all the push messages in Sqlite?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. It's about notifications already received. Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do that. You should have set up your server with logging or done so in your app.

Comment: There is already logging in the server but for some reason people can't find :) so we are trying to find in the device.

Comment: Waste of energy, find it on the server.

Comment: It should be findable with device id and date, right? But they can't find them and we forgot the content of the notifications. So we wanted to see them in the device again, to give server people more details to search.

Comment: It depend on your server. If the server doesn't log what it has sent then I don't think there is anything to do :) the server "guys" should be able to figure out where they log stuff by looking into what they do when they send out push.

Comment: You may use getActiveNotifications() method of NotificationListenerService in API >=18.